# Date split-up based on Fiscal Year

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Given a *From Date*, *To Date* and a *Fiscal Year system*, I want to get all the split-up duration within the
given From & To Date based on the Fiscal Year system.  Explained below with examples:

**Example 1:**
Fiscal Year system: Apr to Mar

From Date: Jan-05-2008
To Date: May-15-2008

Based on Fiscal Year system, duration should be splitted into:

```
Jan-05-2008 to Mar-31-2008
Apr-01-2008 to May-15-2008
```

**Example 2:**
Fiscal Year system: Apr to Mar

From Date: Jan-17-2008
To Date: May-20-2009

Based on Fiscal Year system, duration should be splitted into:

```
Jan-17-2008 to Mar-31-2008
Apr-01-2008 to Mar-31-2009
Apr-01-2009 to May-20-2009
```

Am looking for approach/algorithm to solve this in PostgreSQL 8.2.

Regards,

Gnanam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually favor Andomar's solution (with the addition of a processes that automatically fills the Periods table), but for fun here's a solution that doesn't require it.

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (start_date date, end_date date);
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES ('Jan-17-2008', 'May-20-2009');

SELECT
    GREATEST(start_date, ('04-01-'||series.year)::date) AS year_start,
    LEAST(end_date, ('03-31-'||series.year + 1)::date) AS year_end
FROM
    (SELECT
        start_date,
        end_date,
        generate_series(
            date_part('year', your_table.start_date - INTERVAL '3 months')::int,
            date_part('year', your_table.end_date - INTERVAL '3 months')::int)
    FROM your_table) AS series(start_date, end_date, year)
ORDER BY
    start_date;
```

Comment: Hi cope360,
That's really great and it solved my problem in a simple manner.
Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table containing the start and end of all fiscal years, f.e.

```
Periods (PeriodStartDt, PeriodEndDt)
```

Then you can `join` the tables together if they at least partly overlap.  Use a `case` statement to select the end of the period or the end of the row, depending on which is later.  For example (not tested):

```
select      case when yt.StartDt < p.PeriodStartDt then p.PeriodStartDt
                 else yt.StartDt
            end as SplitStart
,           case when yt.EndDt > p.PeriodEndDt then p.PeriodEndDt
                 else yt.EndDt
            end as SplitEnd
,           yt.*
from        YourTable yt
inner join  Periods p
on          yt.StartDt < p.PeriodEndDate
            and yt.EndDt >= p.PeriodStartDate
```

Comment: Let me add some additional inputs on what I require exactly.

MYTABLE (FROMDATE, TODATE)

From Date and To Date are retrieved from a database table.  The split-up duration has to be found 
programatically in plpgsql and not to be matched with the records.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (start_date date, end_date date); 
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (CONVERT (date, GETDATE()),CONVERT (date, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())) ); 

WITH mycte AS
 (
 SELECT 1 as id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id + 1
 FROM mycte
 WHERE id + 1 < = 12
 ),
 cte_distribution as
 (
 SELECT *, 
 DATEPART (month,DATEADD(month, mycte.id - 1, your_table.start_date)) as month_number ,
 DATEPART (YEAR,DATEADD(month, mycte.id - 1, your_table.start_date)) as  cal_year,
 12000/12 as cash
 FROM your_table
 CROSS JOIN mycte
 )
 select 
 *,
 (CASE WHEN month_number between 1 and 3 THEN '1st quarter' WHEN month_number between 4 and 6 THEN '2nd quarter'  WHEN month_number between 7 and 9 THEN '3rd quarter' WHEN month_number between 9 and 12 THEN '4th quarter' END) as Quarter,
 CASE WHEN month_number between 1 and 6 THEN  CAST(CAST((cal_year - 1) as CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(cal_year as CHAR(4)) AS CHAR(9))  WHEN  month_number between 6 and 12 THEN CAST(CAST((cal_year) as CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST((cal_year + 1) as CHAR(4)) AS CHAR(9))  ELSE NULL END as fin_year
 from cte_distribution;
```