# Date split-up based on break-up

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, postgresql

Given a From Date, To Date, Fiscal Year system.  I want to get all the split-up duration within the given duration based on the breakup asked for.

Breakups are:
1) *Weekly*:    This should be followed from Monday through Sunday.
2) *Monthly*:   This should be 1st of a month through end of the month.
3) *Quarterly*
    Since the Fiscal Year system is Apr-Mar, quarterly breakups should be Apr-Jun, Jul-Sep, Oct-Dec, Jan-Mar
4) *Half-yearly*:
    Since the Fiscal Year system is Apr-Mar, half-yearly breakups should be Apr-Sep, Oct-Mar.
5) *Annual*:
    Since the Fiscal Year system is Apr-Mar, annual breakup should be Apr-Mar.

Explained below with examples.
**Example 1:**
From Date: Feb-10-2010
To Date: Feb-10-2010
Fiscal Year system: Apr to Mar

Weekly Breakup: Feb-08-2010 to Feb-14-2010
Monthly Breakup: Feb-01-2010 to Feb-28-2010
Quarterly Breakup: Jan-01-2010 to Mar-31-2010
Half-yearly Breakup: Oct-01-2009 to Mar-31-2010
Annual Breakup: Apr-01-2009 to Mar-31-2010

Am looking for approach/algorithm to solve this in PostgreSQL 8.2.

This post is similar to a question posted here:
[Date split-up based on Fiscal Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167755/date-split-up-based-on-fiscal-year)

Comment: This is an old post, but the question is ambiguous as to the expected output, the answer isn't really all that helpful either, it is advice, but not a direct solution. It's probably best to just close this one straight off, any effort to fix this involves too many assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to do this in code it may be worth using a calendar table keyed on date and with period attributes.
e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE calendar_day (
day_date DATE PRIMARY KEY,
week_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
month_number SMALLINT NOT NULL,
quarter_number SMALLINT NOT NULL,
demi_year_number SMALLINT NOT NULL,
fiscal_year SMALLINT NOT NULL);
```

This can be populated fairly easily using generate_series() and postgresql date functions and then used to join according to the date criteria you wish to use

Comment: There are situations where date tables make a lot of sense, I'm not convinced this is one of them, not when the calculation is straight forward and you are not going to filter on the results of the calculation.