# Postgresql split date range by year parts (financial year)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like follows:

```
id  start_date   end_date
1   2020-01-01   2020-05-01
2   2020-03-01   2021-04-02
```

I need to be able to split the rows by financial year e.g. 2020-04-01 -> 2021-03-31)

So the result of the query would be as follows:

```
id  start_date   end_date
1   2020-01-01   2020-03-31
1   2020-04-01   2020-05-01
2   2020-03-01   2020-03-31
2   2020-04-01   2021-03-31
2   2021-04-01   2021-04-02
```

Comment: Need more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually another post helped me resolve this:  [Date split-up based on Fiscal Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167755/date-split-up-based-on-fiscal-year)

```
DROP TABLE your_table;
CREATE TABLE your_table (id int, start_date date, end_date date);
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (1, '2020-01-01', '2020-05-01');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (2, '2020-03-01', '2021-04-02');

SELECT
    id,
    GREATEST(start_date, ('01-04-'||series.year)::date) AS year_start,
    LEAST(end_date, ('31-03-'||series.year + 1)::date) AS year_end
FROM
    (SELECT
        id,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        generate_series(
            date_part('year', your_table.start_date - INTERVAL '3 months')::int,
            date_part('year', your_table.end_date - INTERVAL '3 months')::int)
    FROM your_table) AS series(id, start_date, end_date, year)
ORDER BY
    start_date;
```

Result:

```
"id","year_start","year_end"
  1,"2020-01-01","2020-03-31"
  1,"2020-04-01","2020-05-01"
  2,"2020-03-01","2020-03-31"
  2,"2020-04-01","2021-03-31"
  2,"2021-04-01","2021-04-02"
```